# cv2 in Python crashes when I try to open a 4 level CMYK numpy array

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2

with Image.open("image.png") as im:
   
    im = im.convert("CMYK")# not a true CMYK conversion here  
    im.show(title="image")
    img = np.array(im)
    #cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

I need to view a CMYK file hopefully using OpenCV and read pixel values in the CMYK space. I tried to load an image, convert it to CMYK(just 4 color levels) and view it using cv2. Note, I have cv2* commented out because it will cause Python to crash and OpenCv will need to be reinstalled. Will OpenCv allow me to view a (x, x, 0:3).uint8 numpy array? If so, throw me a line.

Comment: It now works. I forgot the following:

Comment: "crashes"? you didn't give an error message or a proper description of what "crashes" means. you should have said "window appears, but is unresponsive, and the OS offers to end the process". please review [ask] and [mre]. in the preparation of a good question you you might have found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was simple. I forgot the following:

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```